# How to disable popup suggest(or tips) window when typing in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type in:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {}
})
```

Then I add a comma after `container` brace, it always popup a window to tip me some infomations I never watch.

```
container: {},
```

So what is this popup window? eslint tips? or something else?

Is it possible to disable this and how?

[image: annoying popups]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable it with this parameter in user settings, according with [reported issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28380):

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

Comment: As of 2023, this does not disable all/most/some auto suggestions.
Try:
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "off"
  },